# Laravel Query Builder - How can I alias a subquery?

Tags: laravel, query-builder

If I have the following code:

`DB::table('A')->join(DB::table('B'), ...)`

which results in this sql:

`select * from "A" inner join (select * from "B") on ...`

how can I alias that subquery? As in `select * from "A" inner join (select * from "B") as "Boron" on ...`

I'd rather not have to use raw sql.

Comment: how about something like DB::table( DB::raw("(SELECT * FROM b) as Boron") )

Comment: In reality my subquery is actually larger with multiple joins so the raw would be messier than I would have liked...although still an option.

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution for subqueries is *DB::raw* and it can solve aliases as well.

```
        $items = DB::table('A as Amy')
            ->select('*')
            ->join(
                DB::raw("(select * from B) as Boron"),
                'Amy.keyA', '=', 'Boron.keyB')
            ->get();
```

Comment: In that case you could just DB::raw the whole thing. This is what OP was trying to avoid.